# Is there a re-entrancy risk if the contract does not store ether?

Tags: security

Let's say you have a payable function that immediately sends the payable amount to another account.

It is possible for this function to be hacked? Or no? If the contract never ends up storing funds aside from that single function call, wherein it is immediately transferred to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

if you are transferring the `msg.value` without storing it,even if if a hacker tries to call the payable function the moment they received the ether,  they will receive the ether they sent to the payable function and won't receive any new ether.

Comment: Ok, got it. So it's basically impossible, unless there is an error in the sending of the ether, but you could easily get around this by making the calls required, right? What would happen to the ether if the call didn't go through?

Comment: if the call did not go through or error happens, the state change during the function call will  be reverted back to its original state or the previous state before the function call, hence the contract won't receive the ether, it will stay with the user or won't be deducted from the user.